# Rails + Heroku + Cloudfront & S3 Cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am testing my site and got an alert that I don't have any asset caching configured for static images served though S3/Cloudfront. Almost all my get requests return a "X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront" response. I just set this up a couple days ago and all the tutorials say to configure each item and add the headers manually. I have an asset library of 6k icons, so I'd rather have this dealt with where I dont have to set the headers on upload.

I use design.cdn.getsprk.com which is pointed to my cloudfront account, which points to my s3 as the origin. I'm using Rails on Heroku.

I have also tested the headers using the direct s3 link, the cloudfront and custom domains. None are showing the correct headers.

I attached my configuration settings for cloudfront.

Example icon: design.cdn.getsprk.com/icons/space/flat/11-neil-armstrong.svg

Request header:

```
GET /icons/space/flat/11-neil-armstrong.svg HTTP/1.1
Host: design.cdn.getsprk.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
If-None-Match: "746b7f4bce35cf3e6a8c965207087631"
If-Modified-Since: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 23:59:32 GMT
```

Response:

```
Connection:keep-alive
Date:Mon, 16 Nov 2015 22:29:05 GMT
ETag:"746b7f4bce35cf3e6a8c965207087631"
Last-Modified:Tue, 10 Nov 2015 23:59:32 GMT
Server:AmazonS3
Via:1.1 483919577b54800dcfc93dcd11176f74.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:mliY9nJt-2KEyu3aPpsxLm-Vd1LTKLRWYj9dTmfg54Mui0SKVhHL-g==
X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront
```

Cloudfront config:
[image: Cloudfront settings]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making a conditional request, notice the presence of If-None-Match/If-Modified-Since.  If the object is not in cache, it will always be a Miss.  Can you try pressing Ctrl+F5 in your browser to make a non-conditional request?

```
curl --compressed -v -o /dev/null design.cdn.getsprk.com/icons/space/flat/11-neil-armstrong.svg
* About to connect() to design.cdn.getsprk.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 54.192.144.164...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* connected
* Connected to design.cdn.getsprk.com (54.192.144.164) port 80 (#0)
> GET /icons/space/flat/11-neil-armstrong.svg HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: design.cdn.getsprk.com
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
> 
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: image/svg+xml
< Content-Length: 7702
< Connection: keep-alive
< Date: Wed, 18 Nov 2015 00:43:12 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 10 Nov 2015 23:59:32 GMT
< ETag: "746b7f4bce35cf3e6a8c965207087631"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Server: AmazonS3
< Age: 9094
< **X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront**
< Via: 1.1 43ff408868c37128de942a235a1225f2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< X-Amz-Cf-Id: G7VwUZ3l15YnxjbZaeZmeeqSaj_E4OszrsS2sSfFjqkh1ZlTOXoKEg==
< 
{ [data not shown]
100  7702  100  7702    0     0  70606      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  104k
* Connection #0 to host design.cdn.getsprk.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your response is what I should aim for?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by aim for.  My response explained why you might always see a miss on conditional requests.

Comment: Thanks @imperalix I see that on a couple of the svg images now. I'm using a lazy loader for my [icon](http://getsprk.com/style/icons) page since it has a lot of images. Some are showing hit and others are showing miss.

I tried a couple different curl requests:
`curl --compressed -v -o /dev/null http://design.cdn.getsprk.com/icons/arrows/flat/157-move-to-bottom.svg 
< Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Nov 2015 19:22:14 GMT < Age: 209 < X-Cache: Hit from cloudfront`
 vs
`curl --head http://design.cdn.getsprk.com/icons/arrows/flat/157-move-to-bottom.svg < X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront`

Comment: Do I have to configure s3/cloudfront to not pass the If-None-Match/If-Modified-Since headers?

Comment: Once an object is in cache, this continual miss should not happen.  Do you have an example of where you always get misses? Can you curl the same svg object twice?  Also, your are doing a head request while your browser does GETs.

Comment: Gotchya. That makes sense for the curl requests. I'm looking at the network tab in the dev console for http://getsprk.com/style/icons. The misses are coming from some of the images that are loaded when you scroll. After the image with the prefix `20_` is loaded, I'm just seeing "Provisional headers are shown" with no other visible response headers.